# XamlBehaviorsWpf WPF Behaviors not working on KeyUp

Tags: c#, wpf, keyup

I am using the Microsoft [XamlBehaviorsWpf](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf)   [Tag missing! Can someone with a high enough rating please add] in my WPF Application.
I have four behavior triggers in my XAML as shown below.

I'm finding that the `KeyDown` triggers are working fine but the `KeyUp` events are not.

Does anybody know why?

```
xmlns:behaviors="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
....

<behaviors:KeyTrigger Key="LeftCtrl" FiredOn="KeyDown">
    <behaviors:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="CtrlDown"/>
</behaviors:KeyTrigger>
<behaviors:KeyTrigger Key="RightCtrl" FiredOn="KeyDown">
    <behaviors:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="CtrlDown"/>
</behaviors:KeyTrigger>
<behaviors:KeyTrigger Key="LeftCtrl" FiredOn="KeyUp">
    <behaviors:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="CtrlUp"/>
</behaviors:KeyTrigger>
<behaviors:KeyTrigger Key="RightCtrl" FiredOn="KeyUp">
    <behaviors:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="CtrlUp"/>
</behaviors:KeyTrigger>
....
```

and here is my ViewModel

```
    public void CtrlDown()
    {
        cntrlSelected = true;
        MessageBox.Show("down");
    }

    public void CtrlUp()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("up");
        cntrlSelected = false;
    }
```

**EDIT**

Here is a screenshot of the available `FiredOn` options:

[image]

**EDIT 2**

This issue has been raised on GitHub however a response is still pending for 8 months now, so unsure if it's a bug, or I'm (plus others) are not using the library correctly.

Link: [Issue #77](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/issues/77)

Comment: The default implementation of the control may be intercepting `KeyUp` and preventing it from making its way to your behavior. You could verify this by hooking `PreviewKeyUp` instead.

Comment: Hello, I tried like this: <behaviors:KeyTrigger Key="PreviewKeyUp" FiredOn="KeyUp"> but  XamlBehaviorsWpf  doesn't appear to have a PreviewKeyUp event.

Comment: You should reverse those values, you still want the `Key` to be `LeftControl`, but the `FiredOn` should be the name of the event you want to capture, in this case `PreviewKeyUp`.

Comment: I'm afraid `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` are the only options on `FiredOn`, I'll add an screenshot to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm finding that the KeyDown triggers are working fine but the KeyUp events are not

I am able to replicate this behavior myself, and to be honest I am not sure why the `FiredOn` => `KeyUp` isn't working (I would need to investigate more). I also want to thank you for providing the link to the raised issue on GitHub, it seems no one is assigned this issue either as of yet.

I've been able to get around this issue by changing the `TriggerType` to `EventTrigger`, please see below:

**.xaml Changes**

```
<behaviors:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp">
   <behaviors:CallMethodAction MethodName="CtrlUp" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
</behaviors:EventTrigger>
```

With this change, we now need to change the backing viewmodel/code `CtrlUp` method signature. Also worth mentioning is `CallMethodAction` does accept parameters, in this case we do need. Please see below for changes:

```
public void CtrlUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl || e.Key == Key.RightCtrl)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("UP");
   }
}
```

I know this is a work around the actual issue, but it does indeed work. Hopefully the team can investigate the root cause of the problem and get it fixed.

**All Code Used**

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window x:Name="myUserControl"
        x:Class="WpfApp14.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:behaviors="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp14"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="800"
        Height="450"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        >
    <behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
        <behaviors:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp">
            <behaviors:CallMethodAction MethodName="CtrlUp" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
        </behaviors:EventTrigger>
        <behaviors:KeyTrigger Key="LeftCtrl" FiredOn="KeyDown">
            <behaviors:CallMethodAction MethodName="CtrlDown" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
        </behaviors:KeyTrigger>
    </behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>

    <Grid x:Name="grid" />
</Window>
```

*MainWindow.xaml.cs*

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public void CtrlUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl || e.Key == Key.RightCtrl)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("UP");
        }
    }

    public void CtrlDown() => Console.WriteLine("DOWN");
}
```

Also I am using version: `1.1.31` of `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm afraid I can't get this to work. If I take your answer and swap `KeyUp` for `MouseRightButtonDown` and delete the parameters in the Method then the Method fires just fine on a right click. But using `EventTrigger` I'm finding neither `KeyUp` nor `KeyDown` fire. I'll start a new Solution and see if I get the same result.

Comment: Are you 100% sure your solution wasn't working for some other reason? I've tried it in .NetFramework,, .Net 5, and various older versions of XamlBehaviorsWpf and I still find that only mouse events trigger using the `EventTrigger` and only `KeyDown` events trigger using `TriggerType`. It's all very strange. Will do a bit more reading around. Thanks.

Comment: Please see my update, it's all code I've used for testing these changes.

Comment: Ok thanks, I see what I was doing wrong. I had the behaviors in a `UserControl` where I need the focus to be when the keys are used. But it seems `EventTrigger` will only work when used in the main `Window`control. I didn't realise that. Strange that the `TriggerType` works fine in a `UserControl`. But that's great, I can make that work. Thanks for all your help.